# JavaScript: Original target of onkeyup()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a contentEditable field with many dynamically inserted span.

When I use the getTarget() from an onclick() event I'm getting the target as the respective span but with onkeyup() and onkeydown() it gives the target as the div in which the function is called from ( I'm using bubbling to capture the events (if I'm correct))

```
function getTarget(e)
{
    var targ;
    if (!e)
       var e = window.event;
    if (e.target)
       targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement)
       targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
       targ = targ.parentNode;
    return targ;
}
```

Could someone point out why this is happening?
Thank You

Note:
In fact , I just noticed that span is not accepting onkeydown,onkeyup or onkeypress. Only onclick event is triggered.How can I make span accept key event?

```
<div class="myedit" onclick="setcontext(event);" 
                onkeydown="getCursorPos();checkmarkup(this,event);"
                    contentEditable="true" >

                    <span class="context global" >global <br/>

                    <span class="context function" >
                     fun1 hi bye   
                     </span>

                     <div>
                        <span class="context function">
                        fun2
                        </span>
                     </div>

                 </span>
</div>
```

This is the HTML part. Note that I can edit the text  "global" or "fun1 hi bye" or "fun2" by clicking on them or moving the cursor to them. Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I understand `span` is able to receive key events (as it is able to change its contents) so it should be raising the key events. 
Also, even if I add `contenteditable='true'` and `onkeydown="alert('keytest')"`on each `span` it still doesn't raise the event.

If in case it is not possible to capture key events on `span` then is there any other element that I could use that would capture key events but wouldn't change the structure?

Comment: Please indent your code with four spaces instead of HTML-escaping it.

Comment: You can't really press a key "on" `span` or `div` - I guess you mean you press a key inside some form element that is nested below the `span` or `div` tags?

Comment: @Shadowwizard: I meant the text in the div or span .Most the text will be enclosed in span.

Comment: @diff you can't. One way around is catching the global `document.onkeyup` event, raise a flag in the span `onmouseover`, lower that flag in the span `onmouseout` and in the global `keyup` event check: if the flag is raised, it means the key was pressed while hovering over the span otherwise it's not. Hope it makes sense, if you need I can pull quick example.

Comment: I can't imagine a keypress on a span, can you post your HTML?

Comment: Your code can be simplified as https://gist.github.com/870909

Comment: @Livinston Samuel : Thank you for that code. Really much smaller!!

Comment: @Shadow Wizard:But that would give correct results when positioning the cursor with the mouse only,right? What if the user moves the cursor using the arrow keys?

Comment: @diff you mean moving the mouse cursor with arrow keys? I think that `onmouseover` will still be triggered as it's the mouse cursor, it doesn't care how you actually move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a work around for this (but not for IE):

```
function getCurrentElement() //the one in which cursor is there
{
   if (window.getSelection)
   {
    return window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode;
   }
   else if (document.selection)
       {
        alert( "IE not yet supported or tested !!");
       }

}
```

But am still interested in the above queries.
PS.If anybody knows an equivalent method for IE please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You will only receive key events on an element if two things are true:

1. The element can receive focus. (for non-input elements, this means either `contenteditable="true"` or the element has a `tabindex` attribute).
2. The element has focus.

It sounds like you are already using a editable element. However, note that if you have a non-editable span within a contenteditable element, you will still only receive events for the parent element. <strike>You must also make the span editable, and assign it focus.</strike> **Edit:** You can't actually have a contenteditable element within another contenteditable. The outer element always gets focus, even if you manually invoke `.focus()` on the inner one.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but how do I "assign it focus"?

Comment: @diffthinkr `document.getElementById('foo').focus()` (or `$('#foo').focus()` with jQuery).

Comment: @Nathan Ostgard : Thank you but this means that I have to do it via code, right? Then my need to detect the word the user selects is not fulfilled!      Also, if some text is gettting entered into an area, then doesn't it mean that it is already having focus?

Comment: @diffthinkr Ahh, I just saw that you added your HTML. I made a mistake: you can't have a contenteditable nested in a contenteditable. I don't think you can do what you want, as it would mean disabling contenteditable on the main div. Are you trying to syntax highlight or something?

Comment: @Nathan : Yes, I'm working on syntax highlighting.I have found a workaround for browsers other than IE. I wonder why people make standards if the major players don't bother sticking to them!!!